# Is there any GUI for for using Drools?

Tags: user-interface, drools

I am new to Drools. I have already integrated Drools with jsp. Now I want to know is there any 
GUI for Drools to run its application?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drools Guvnor is the web GUI for managing rules:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html_single/

If you want a good overview of how Guvnor is used, it's worth checking out Michael Anstis's videos:

http://vimeo.com/user5347768/videos

When it comes to running rules, that's obviously down to you to write your own application which integrates business rules.

As 'salaboy' mentions in his answer, coming soon as part of Drools 6, there is Drools Workbench. This is a major re-working of Guvnor. The following blog post lets you know what to expect:

http://blog.athico.com/2013/06/goodbye-guvnor-hello-drools-workbench.html

Comment: Hello Steve, I saw this documentation. I am little confused regarding Drools Guvnor. Would you brief me about this topic or there is any other link regarding this topic. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a link to Michael Anstis's videos of Drools Guvnor in use. That's probably the easiest way to get an idea of what it is and how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

we are about to release version 6, which comes with the KIE-Workbench. Look at the web page and the docs to read about it. It will allow you to author and manage rules and business processes.

Comment: Thanks.shall I refer Drools Guvnor for Documentation?