# graphical interface for Drools

Tags: eclipse, drools

i am using Drools for the first time. I downloaded eclipse plugin for drools. I created one sample Drool project.  I want to know is there any Graphical Interface for Drool for eclipse IDE? Drools 6.0 comes with its own work bench but how to integrate with eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed GEF ?

> GEF is the Eclipse Graphical Editing Framework, which is used for
>   graph viewing components in the plug-in.
>
> If you don't have GEF installed, you can install it using the built in
>   update mechanism (or downloading GEF from the Eclipse.org website not
>   recommended). JBoss IDE has GEF already, as do many other
>   "distributions" of Eclipse, so this step may be redundant for some
>   people.
>
> Open the Help->Software updates...->Available Software->Add Site...
>   from the help menu. Location is:
>
> http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/
>
> Next you choose the GEF plug-in

see section [3.1.3.1](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch03.html)

Comment: Thank you. but in eclipse there is no option called SoftWareUpdates under Help

Comment: try `install new software`

Comment: GEF is the Graphical interface for drools? With GEF can i create the rules using GUI instead of writing rules?

Comment: check answer of this post, it might be `guvnor` you're looking for  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046788/is-there-any-gui-for-for-using-drools